# How do I mention fields in kusto that has a dot or period?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am ingesting data from telegraf to ADX. my data has a json field called tag.

```
tag:{org.siteid:"lalala","org.subsid":"xyz"}
```

So, i am trying to form a kusto query to look for a particular site. but I am unable to escape the dot in the field name "org.siteid"

.

this is what i tried:

```
tablename
| where fields.attempt == 0 and tags."org.siteid" contains "car";

tablename
| where fields.registration_management_requests == 0 and tags.org\.siteid contains "car";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer columns which contains dot then you can use them like `['field.name']`.

Below is query with sample data.

**Query**

```
datatable (TimeGenerated : datetime , Type : string , ['User.PrincipalName'] : string ) 
[ 
datetime(2007-04-03 00:00:00.0000000), "type1", "UserPrincipalName1", 
datetime(2007-04-03 01:00:00.0000000), "type1", "UserPrincipalName1", 
datetime(2007-04-05 02:00:00.0000000), "type1", "UserPrincipalName2", 
datetime(2007-04-05 06:00:00.0000000), "type1", "UserPrincipalName1", 
datetime(2007-04-05 06:00:00.0000000), "type1", "UserPrincipalName1" 
] 
| where Type == "type1" 
and ['User.PrincipalName'] == "UserPrincipalName1"
```

**Result**

[image]